# CSS File showing in Live Server but not in Preview/Browser

Tags: html, css, github

I have downloaded the Github website of my university to have the lecture slides saved locally, but the Preview only shows the pure html. Only when I open it in Live Server I get the website rendered with CSS.

I have already tried changing the CSS Filepath (from "href="./Files/stylesheet.css" to "href="Files/stylesheet.css" and "href="../Files/stylesheet.css"), but by doing that, Liveserver doesn't register the CSS Files anymore, and neither does Preview.

I once had a similar problem, but there the LiveServer didn't render the CSS but the Preview/Browser did. Changing the Filepath fixed that problem. This time however it doesn't make a difference.

Does this has something to do with the CSS File itself?